# Find the least upper bound of a binomial distribution

Tags: probability, binomial-distribution, upper-lower-bounds

In this problem we are given a random variable $X$ of binomial with $n=119 ,p=0.5$.
I have calculated $\mathbf{E}[X]=59.5$ and $\mathbf{Var}[X]=29.75$. Looking for $D$ in order to have $\Pr[|X-\mathbf{E}[X]| \ge D] = a$ and use that probability to find the least upper bound for $a$ by using Chebyshev's inequality.

Comment: Do you have given the value of $a$?

Comment: I am supposed to find D first then use it to calculate a.

Comment: Without additional information you cannot find a value for $D$.